# How can I create an {ApplicationName}.app bundle when I have only the executable from make output?

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, cmake, url-scheme

I have Qt/C++ project and I want to create a Mac OS version of it. I have written it with the cmake mechanism using CMakeLists  and makefile build. One of it's features is that you can execute it with a custom URI scheme so the official Mac OS documentation says that it must be written on Info.plist, but the make build output only an executable and not a bundle like {ApplicationName}.app. Is there any tool to bundle the executable to {ApplicationName}.app style?

Comment: You can always create simple "empty shell" and fill it with your application. Take a look here for a sample: http://www.owsiak.org/how-do-i-work-with-development-build-on-macos-netbeans-11-0/

Answer (score 2):

What @chatzich said, and

```
add_executable(appName MACOSX_BUNDLE
        ${mySources}
        ${myResources}
    )
```

There are other things to be done if you wish to redistribute your work, like running `macdeployqt` on the app to help bundle the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You must first set 
set_target_properties(appName PROPERTIES_MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)
and
set(TARGET_EXE build_dir/appName.app/Contents/MacOS/appName)

Answer (score 0):

add the code to comakeList.txt

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE
        main.cpp
        )

set_target_properties(yourProjectName PROPERTIES
            BUNDLE True
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME yourProjectName
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE "0.1"
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION "0.1"
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING "0.1"
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_LS_SYS_VERSION "10.13.4"
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST absolutePath of MacOSXBundleInfo.plist.in
            )

include(CPack)
```